# @i18n not working in rich text editor in AEM

Tags: aem, sightly

I am working in AEM 6.3 using sightly, the @i18n API is not working with rich text editor as the ${properties.text} value takes along with the HTML tags (like `<p>`,`<h1>`,etc.,). So it doesn't match the sling:key property in the i18n dictionary and the conversion is not working.

So can someone help me out with this issue.

Comment: Usually you have one RTE for every language you support. Either in the same dialog or what most people do is having a language copy of the page for every language. So if your project is called `SuperBank` you might have `/content/superbank/en`, `/content/superbank/de`, `/content/superbank/fr` etc. AEM supports this out of the box: See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/sites/msm.html and https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/sites/translation.html